# Selenium Python not scraping from this website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to interact with this website using Selenium in python. I wrote this code to select the radio button using XPATH. But some weird error is showing in my terminal. Can anyone please solve this problem? I tried but can't figure out the problem.

My code.

```
from select import select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/Offender/Pages/InmateSearch.aspx')

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]')
button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.quit()
```

Error :

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62348/devtools/browser/ce37da62-856d-4159-ad45-9eca8e63115a
E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\test.py:18: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_xpath is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath) instead
  button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]')
  File "E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 526, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Fiverr job\Orders\1\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x0054D953+2414931]
        Ordinal0 [0x004DF5E1+1963489]
        Ordinal0 [0x003CC6B8+837304]
        Ordinal0 [0x003F9500+1021184]
        Ordinal0 [0x003F979B+1021851]
        Ordinal0 [0x00426502+1205506]
        Ordinal0 [0x004144E4+1131748]
        Ordinal0 [0x00424812+1198098]
        Ordinal0 [0x004142B6+1131190]
        Ordinal0 [0x003EE860+976992]
        Ordinal0 [0x003EF756+980822]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007BCC62+2510274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007AF760+2455744]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x005DEABA+551962]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x005DD916+547446]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E5F3B+1990459]
        Ordinal0 [0x004EA898+2009240]
        Ordinal0 [0x004EA985+2009477]
        Ordinal0 [0x004F3AD1+2046673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7648FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BE7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BE7A4E+238]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the element you try to click is located into an `iframe`:

[image]

So you must first switch to it before finding and clicking the desired button:

```
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/Offender/Pages/InmateSearch.aspx')

#wait a little to be sure the iframe is loaded
time.sleep(2)

#find and switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="soi-iframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]')
button.click()

driver.quit()
```

Proof of work: (*click on pic to zoom in*)

[image]